# How do I define a generic type alias for something recursive (like an s-expression) in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I tried `type Sexp<T> = Array<T|Sexp<T>>` but it has a circular reference problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works just fine, since version 3.7 where they [changed the resolution rules](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7/#more-recursive-type-aliases) for recursive type aliases. For older version you can use the interface trick:

```js
// Works since 3.7
type Sexp<T> = Array<T | Sexp<T>>;

// Works in older versions
type SexpOlder<T> = SexpArray<T>;
interface SexpArray<T> extends Array<T | SexpArray<T>> {}

const foo: Sexp<number> = [32, [45]];
```

[or see in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEHUHsCcGsGdTwJYDsDGBTUBmAdAOwCwAUAC4CeADtgMqYAeVAPACoB8oAvKAILTQAhhTagAPqHpM27dgG5SpEBBgJQaUJAA2AE0zRQAN30pIqeErCUakxiw7dbTfkJEcFJZWjL6AZoKwnKhdhGVBGH1QdRBC3cSDYmU4AbwBfRRJ0M3gyUF9ISAAuIOZUAFcAWwAjfU4eAG0cACYAGlB6gBYAVgBdHo8gA)